# Coffeescript async and scope

Tags: javascript, http, asynchronous, coffeescript, hubot

I have an array of URLs that I'm fetching and processing, the keys of which I would like to be able to reference when the data returns. What is the preferred way to ensure that a value determined before an asynchronous HTTP call is carried into the closure to be performed when the data returns? In the following example, the `calendar_name` variable is (as expected) lost when the data from the HTTP call returns, and I need to be able to reference that value inside the closure:

```
cals = {
  "calendar one":"http://example.com/info/webcal/abc123.ics",
  "calendar two":"http://example.com/info/webcal/xyz789.ics"
}
for calendar_name,calendar_url of cals
  # Note that this is a Hubot script and the following line performs an HTTP call
  msg.http(calendar_url)
    .get() (err, res, body) ->
      if res.statusCode is 200 and !err?
        ics = ical.parseICS(body)
        event_list = []
        for _, event of ics
          if event.type == 'VEVENT'
            event_list.push event.summary
        console.log("Scheduled events for " + calendar_name)
        for event, k in event_list
          console.log(event)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You're asking why only the last calendar name value is available in the callback [e.g., see all the related js questions about this)?

Comment: I'm not asking why, I understand logically why this is happening. I'm asking how I can work around it so that the variable outside of the callback scope is preserved for future use _within_ the callback. If there's a JS question (or better yet, a Coffeescript question) that addresses this I'd love the assist.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that duplicate is the right one, let me know if I got it wrong.

Comment: Nailed it, @muistooshort. Thanks for the help, I did a bunch of searching and just couldn't find the right answer. Cheers!

Comment: No worries, it is a lot easier to find the duplicate when you already know the answer.